# Why is $\{y_1,y_2 \}$ a basis for $K$?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

I have started reading Smith normal form from this above note. In this note I have failed to understand why is $\{y_1,y_2 \}$  a basis for $K$. It is clear that $\mathrm {span} \{y_1,y_2 \} \subset K$. But I couldn't manage to prove the converse. Please give me some suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $2 = \dim (\text{span} \{y_1, y_2\}) \le \dim (K) \le \dim (\mathbb{Z}^2) = 2$. Is this correct ?

Comment: What you have stated here is true for any module over a PID. In particular $\mathbb Z$ is a PID so this result holds here too. But what is your claim here? Do you claim that if a module over a PID has rank $2$ then any linearly independent set of $2$ elements from it will generate it? But I am quite unsure about that. Though it holds for any general vector space I don't quite aware about whether it holds good or not for any module or at least for modules over a PID.

Comment: No it doesn't hold for modules; in particular modules over a PID. Take for instance $\mathbb Z^2$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module.